# Call a method when a certain property changes

Tags: angular

I have a method I want to run anytime a certain property in my component changes. The value comes from an Input from another component.

Whenever `myValue` changes I would like to call the `myMethod` method.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() myValue: any;

  myValue: any;

  constructor() {}

  private myMethod() {
    // Called when this.myValue changes
  }
}
```

Comment: Implement ngOnChages and test for change there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it using the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook or using a setter combined with `@Input`

Here is the solution with `ngOnChanges`

```js
import { OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() myValue: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if(changes && changes.myValue) {
     this.myMethod();
   }
  
  }

  private myMethod() {
    // Called when this.myValue changes
  }
}
```

And here with the setter.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {
  private _myValue: any;

  @Input() set myValue(value: any) {
    this._myValue = any;
    this.myMethod();
  }
  
  get myValue(): any {
    return this._myValue;
  }

  constructor() {}

  private myMethod() {
    // Called when this.myValue changes
  }
}
```